# Joining two polygons into one attribute table entry while maintaining separate boundaries

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I am trying to combine two polygons into one attribute table entry while keeping their polygon shapes separate (it's a contested area within a larger area) using QGIS. The closest option I've found is collect geometries, which on the surface accomplishes this but gives an error for self-intersection when when I check the validity of the resulting polygon. Has anyone been in a similar situation / have any suggestions on how to approach this?

[image: here's a picture of the two polygons]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE. You may get more responses to your question if you could add screenshots showing what your geometries look like and where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the geometry of overlapping polygons, since the collection does not allow self-intersection.

You can find the exact location causing the errors with the [Check validity](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgischeckvalidity) tool.

[image]